# php database insert not working according to plan

Tags: mysql

This code is throwing an error i tried to troubleshoot but I'm missing something . Since I wrote it I'm overlooking a syntax error. Any help ?

```
$kql="
INSERT INTO References (Email, Company1, Person1, Contact1, Company2, Person2, Contact2, Company3, Person3, Contact3, Company4, Person4, Contact4, Company5, Person5, Contact5)
VALUES ( '$company44','$Company', '$Person', '$Contact', '$Company1', '$Person1', '$Contact1', '$Company2', '$Person2', '$Contact2', '$Company3', '$Person3', '$Contact3', '$Company4', '$Person4', '$Contact4')";
```

The error is

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'References (Email, Company1, Person1, Contact1, Company2, Person2, Contact2, Com' at line 1

Comment: I think it throws an error because `References` is actually a [keyword](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?101,665004,665004) *(atleast for MySQL)*. Try doing a simple `SELECT` in the table, if the error still occurs

Comment: Try to insert the query using  phpMyadmin by replacing the variable with a dummy data

Comment: What DBMS are you using ? MySQL, MS SQL? pgSQL ?

Comment: @Swellar it's used in MSSQL and pgSQL too

Comment: @Cid Thanks for the info, unfortunately I cannot edit my initial comment

Comment: The DBMS im using is MYSQL

Comment: Please do not create SQL queries by joining strings together. You should always use parametrised queries, otherwise you have a significant security risk from SQL injection.
Also, using a parametrised form will make your code much more robust. For example, as it stands, if `$person` was a "Mr O'brien" his name would close your quotation mark in the middle of his name, causing a new syntax error.

Comment: @Swellar your first answered assisted me , created a table with different DB name and it worked.

Comment: always write code with standards, and you will not have such errors

Answer (score 1):

`REFERENCES` Is a SQL keyword used to define a *foreign key*.

If you have a table/col named with a SQL keyword, you have to wrap the table/col name into specific characters.

**MySQL**

```
INSERT INTO `References` (...) ...
```

**MS SQL**

```
INSERT INTO [References] (...) ...
```

**Postgre SQL**

```
INSERT INTO "References" (...) ...
```

I'm not sure concerning pgSQL, can someone confirm?

---

In example, nothing (but common sense) prevents you from creating a database named `INSERT` with a table `INTO` having a column `VALUE(42)`

[image]

This query works :

```
USE [INSERT]
SELECT [INTO].[VALUE(42)] FROM [INTO]
```