# Create Table in mySQL with a name that includes a hyphon, percent symbol, full stop etc

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to create tables in mySQL with names that include hyphons, full stops, the % symbol and others. The name will be in a variable called image_name. How do I go about this? Of course I could replace all with underscores, but that is suboptimal. Is the default collation wrong?

My Code:

```
$image_name = 'abc_def.ghi%';

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $image_name(
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
film_name VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
...
)";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Table of image $image_name created successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea.  Why do you want to do this?  If there aren't actual words to describe the names of your tables then it sounds like you may have a design problem somewhere.

Comment: use backticks for that

Comment: Why? Why? **WHY?**

Comment: @SalmanA why not, eh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using backticks around field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names)

Comment: Let the OP answer it. He does not have a clue how to do this and will run into more problems down the road.

Comment: `The dot is the reference operator in SQL` and using special characters not a good practice, use `_` in your table name, this is the best practice.

Comment: @David The names of the tables are given to me like that. There is nothing I can do about that. There are actual words of course, but some do contain these characters.

Comment: then you can clear this charcaters by using php @KevinQiu before creating tables

Comment: @KevinQiu: It still seems *very likely* that there's an overall better approach to whatever you're trying to do.  Why are you building a system where people are directly managing database schemas?  There are already products where people can login to a database and manage schemas.

Comment: if you found `_` in image name, then ignore, if you found `.` then you can replace it with `_`, if you found `%` in your image name replace with empty, make it easy for other people, who will work after you :)

Comment: Guys, there is nothing wrong badly naming tables, to grant you a lifetime job because no one could maintain your DB/Code (No, seriously, never do that). Reminds me [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52621998/8398549) I posted few monthes ago

Comment: @Cid: *"because no one could maintain your DB/Code"* - *Everything* is wrong with that.

Comment: @David this is sarcasm

Comment: @Cid: Sarcasm which may be missed by the OP because, well, this very question.

Comment: Yep got the point I edited the comment

Answer (score 1):

You should surround the table names with backticks - ``

Answer (score 1):

The table name has to surrounded by backticks.

[**SQL DEMO**](https://rextester.com/AQH21757)

```
CREATE TABLE `abc_def.ghi%` (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    film_name VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL
)
```